# Progressively erase tail of a Python list

Tags: python, beginner

Hey I started programming in python few days ago and decided to write a programme without any tutorial. You give it a list and then my programme erases last item of list until there's only one item. I know my code can be improved easily and also I dont know how to display text like "Ok, fine" when user chooses "No" in input part. I'm noob in python but wanna learn it so I appreciate every advice to make my programme better.

```
import time
a=["orange","avocado","mango","apple","grape","banana"]
print(" ".join(a))
time.sleep(1)
b=["orange","avocado","mango","apple","grape","banana"]

while True:
   x = (int(len(a)) - 1)
   if x > 0:
       del a[x]
       print(" ".join(a))
       time.sleep(1)
       if int(len(a)) == 1:
           print("Nothing more to cut")
           print("--------------------")
   if x <= 0:
       run_once = 0
       while 1:
           if run_once == 0:
               guess = input("Want to reverse what we just did? Yes/No : ")
               if guess == "yes" or guess == "Yes" or guess=="YES":
                   print(b[0])
                   time.sleep(1)
                   print(b[0], b[1])
                   time.sleep(1)
                   print(b[0], b[1], b[2])
                   time.sleep(1)
                   print(b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3])
                   time.sleep(1)
                   print(b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4])
                   time.sleep(1)
                   print(b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5])
                   time.sleep(1)
                   print("Done!")
               run_once = 1
```

Comment: It seems part of the implementation is missing (the `No` part, hint: use an [`elif`](https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/en/latest/book/06_control_structures/if_else.html)). If you take a look at the [help/on-topic], you'll notice code has to actually work before we review it.

Comment: Code Review is for improving code which already works the way you want. As such you should remove the request to implement the "Ok, fine" from your question. Please [edit] your question and remove the following text "I dont know how to display text like "Ok, fine" when user chooses "No" in input part.".

Answer (score 3):

Don't `sleep` - it offers no value.

Rather than verbatim rewriting your `b` list with the same literal as the `a` list, just make a copy calling `list()`.

`len(a)` does not need to be re-cast to an `int` as it already is one.

`del` can be substituted with a simple `pop()` call.

The user has not input a `guess` - they are not guessing whether the program will continue; they're making a choice - so you should name the variable accordingly.

You can simplify your input check by looking only at the first letter of the input string in lower-case.

Your repeated `print(b[i]` should be replaced with a loop.

`run_once` is unnecessary and should be deleted.

### Suggested

```
fruits = ["orange", "avocado", "mango", "apple", "grape", "banana"]
original_fruits = list(fruits)


def print_fruits():
    print(" ".join(fruits))

print_fruits()

while len(fruits) > 1:
    fruits.pop()
    print_fruits()

print("Nothing more to cut")
print("--------------------")

choice = input("Want to reverse what we just did? Yes/No: ")
if not choice.lower().startswith('y'):
    exit()

while len(fruits) < len(original_fruits):
    fruits.append(original_fruits[len(fruits)])
    print_fruits()

print("Done!")
```

### Output

```
orange avocado mango apple grape banana
orange avocado mango apple grape
orange avocado mango apple
orange avocado mango
orange avocado
orange
Nothing more to cut
--------------------
Want to reverse what we just did? Yes/No: y
orange avocado
orange avocado mango
orange avocado mango apple
orange avocado mango apple grape
orange avocado mango apple grape banana
Done!
```

Comment: wow tyvm I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

### An absurdist code review containing good advice

**Prefer command-line arguments over interactivity**. Interactive scripts are
mostly a hassle. They are more difficult to write, debug, and evolve over time
because every execution requires a tedious human-computer dialogue.
Command-line arguments are a well-established mechanism for building useful
programs. The sooner you embrace them, the better.

**Prefer constants over mutable variables**. A list changing size in a
computer's brain is sort of like a tree falling in a forest: did it really
happen, do we really care? To the end-user, the list appears to be shrinking
and expanding, and we're under no obligation to tell them otherwise: *how we
achieve the magic is an implementation detail*.

```
import sys

FRUITS = ['orange', 'avocado', 'mango', 'apple', 'grape', 'banana']

args = sys.argv[1:]
reverse = args and args[0] == '--reverse'

n = len(FRUITS)
shrinking = list(range(n, 0, -1))
expanding = list(range(2, n + 1)) if reverse else []

for i in shrinking + expanding:
    print(' '.join(FRUITS[0 : i]))
```

**Prefer data-creation over data destruction**. And if that approach is too
deceptive for the pure-of-heart, perhaps spawning a bunch of *effectively*
shrunken or expanded lists will do the trick. That approach leads directly
to one of the most important topics: **organizing programs around
functions that receive and return data**.

```
import sys

FRUITS = ['orange', 'avocado', 'mango', 'apple', 'grape', 'banana']

def main(args):
    reverse = args and args[0] == '--reverse'
    for fb in create_fruit_baskets(FRUITS, reverse):
        print(' '.join(fb))

def create_fruit_baskets(fruits, reverse = False):
    n = len(fruits)
    shrinking = list(range(n, 0, -1))
    expanding = list(range(2, n + 1)) if reverse else []
    return [
        fruits[0 : i]
        for i in shrinking + expanding
    ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```